# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404() /Content/css/?v=jRhCwhzcqoKX5UO6Ep4Zb2Fys6l96h5HP2M3bMA_9hk1:1" on publish in IIS

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, iis, vs-web-application-project

i have devloped the c# asp.net web application with master page. its working fine in localhost but when i publish it in IIS. it is not run properly,
inside the devloper tools find the error
"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
/Content/css/?v=jRhCwhzcqoKX5UO6Ep4Zb2Fys6l96h5HP2M3bMA_9hk1:1"

<webopt:bundlereference runat="server" path="~/Content/css" />
bootstrap.css (Bootstrap-v5.2.3) and site.css files are inside this folder path..
i am using visual studio 2019, .Net famwork 4.8 and IIS-10.

I tried by many way to solve this problem but i could not get sucesss...
Please help me....
Thanks...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue happens when you really have a css folder in Content. The site.css file should be in the "Content" folder directly despite the path is "~/Content/css". You can compare with visual studio default webform application, there won't be a css folder in the published files. You can rename this folder.

The other thing you can try is in the web.config, in the section of `<system.web>`
add

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.8">
```